# Trying to catch concurrent modification exception in Firestore in Datastore mode

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I am trying to catch a concurrent modification exception in Firestore in Datastore mode with Objectify. I created a method and ran it 50 times in 1 second to try and catch the exception. I found that I can only catch the exception if I use a transaction.

Is there a way to catch the CME without a transaction?

This does **not** catch the exception when ran 50 times in 1 second (even though I can see in the logs the entity is not always updated due to the 1/sec write limit):

```
try {
    Entity entity = ofy().load().type(Entity.class)
        .filter("username", "username1")
        .first()
        .now();
    entity.setName("username2")
    ofy().save().entity(newEntity).now();
} catch (com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreException datastoreException) {
    // Never catches anything
} catch (Exception e) {
    // Never catches anything
}
```

This catches the exception when ran 50 times in 1 second:

```
try {
    ofy().transact(new VoidWork() {
        public void vrun() {
                Entity entity = ofy().load().type(Entity.class)
                    .filter("username", "username1")
                    .first()
                    .now();
                entity.setName("username2")
                ofy().save().entity(newEntity).now();
                }
            }
    });
} catch (com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreException datastoreException) {
    // Catches this error: Aborted due to cross-transaction contention. This occurs when multiple transactions attempt to access the same data, requiring Firestore to abort at least one in order to enforce serializability.
} catch (Exception e) {
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a transaction the write is concerned a blind write.  A blind write writes the content of the write even if another write has happened between your read & your write.

You should not expect a concurrent modification exception without a transaction.

Comment: That makes sense that it is a blind write. But how come I will get a log entry saying "too much contention" when writing the entity too much without a transaction? Somehow, on the backend it must be catching it and write that log. Since I saw it, I thought maybe I could catch it myself as well.